# Office 365 Powershell - Export user, license type, and company field to csv file

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365

I need to be able to export user name or email address (doesn't matter which), company (from the company field under the organization tab in a user account of the exchange admin console), and license type (e.g. exchange online e1, exchange online kiosk etc...)

I am able to export both values in two statements into two separate files but that doesn't do me much good.

I can export the username and license type with the following:

```
Get-MSOLUser | % { $user=$_; $_.Licenses | Select {$user.displayname},AccountSKuid } | Export-CSV "sample.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

And, I can get the company values with the following:

```
Get-User | select company | Export-CSV sample.csv
```

Someone on another forum suggested this -

```
$index = @{}
Get-User | foreach-object {$index.Add($_.userprincipalname,$_.company)}
Get-MsolUser | ForEach-Object { write-host $_.userprincipalname, $index[$_.userprincipalname], $_.licenses.AccountSku.Skupartnumber}
```

That seems like it should work but it doesn't display any license info in my powershell, it's just blank.  Also I wouldn't know how to export that to a csv file.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Slight fix to support the newest commandlets:

- Line 4 updated to "$UserInfo = Get-MSOLUser -UserPrincipalName $msolUser.UserPrincipalName"
- Line 2: Add -All param

---

```
$lines = @()    foreach($msolUser in (Get-MSOLUser -All))    {
   $UserInfo = Get-MSOLUser -UserPrincipalName $msolUser.UserPrincipalName
   foreach($license in $msolUser.Licenses)
   {
       $lines += New-Object PsObject -Property @{
                   "Username"="$($UserInfo.DisplayName)";
                   "Company"="$($UserInfo.Company)";
                   "AccountSKUID"="$($license.AccountSKUid)"
                 }
   }    }    $lines | Export-CSV C:\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

It worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 4):

This will export the licensed users with license type

```
Get-MsolUser -All |
  Where {$_.IsLicensed -eq $true } |
  Select DisplayName,UsageLocation,@{n="Licenses Type";e={$_.Licenses.AccountSKUid}},SignInName,UserPrincipalName,@{n="ProxyAddresses";e={$_.ProxyAddresses}} | 
  Export-Csv -Path C:\_Cory\Test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 3):

In the first example you select the `AccountSkuId` property and in the second you go for `AccountSKU.SkuPartNumber` (which I'm pretty sure doesn't exist).

You're script/one-liner is also not too easy to read, how about this:

```
$lines = @()
foreach($msolUser in (Get-MSOLUser))
{
    $UserInfo = Get-User -Identity $msolUser.UserPrincipalName
    foreach($license in $msolUser.Licenses)
    {
        $lines += @{
                    "Username"="$($UserInfo.DisplayName)";
                    "Company"="$($UserInfo.Company)";
                    "AccountSKUID"="$($license.AccountSKUid)"
                  }
    }
}
$lines | Export-CSV C:\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Much easier to get an overview of and maintain.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't really know powershell or scripting, all those commands were ones I found in other forums etc...

I copy and pasted your commands into powershell and the output did not look right in the csv file.  Please see the image for an example - [link](http://i.imgur.com/4j4CyHM.png)

Comment: If you don't really understand the above or know what you're looking for, and you're venturing into Office 365 management I strongly suggest the following: 1) Read through some of the [great](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/powershell.aspx) [resources](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd793612) for [powershell](http://powershell.org/wp/) online. 2) Get familiar with the [Office 365 Powershell basics](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh750396.aspx)

Comment: OK.  I just needed this one output every month for billing purposes, I'm not trying to manage office 365.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this and it's PERFECT
THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!

```
$lines = @()
foreach($msolUser in (Get-MSOLUser -ALL | where {$_.isLicensed -eq $true}))
{
    $UserInfo = Get-User -identity $msolUser.UserPrincipalName
    foreach($license in $msolUser.Licenses)
    {
        $lines += New-Object PsObject -Property @{
                    "Nom/Prenom"="$($UserInfo.DisplayName)";
                    "Societe"="$($UserInfo.Company)";
                    "AdressePrincipale"="$($UserInfo.UserPrincipalName)";
                    "Licences"="$($license.AccountSKUid)"
                  }
    }
}
$lines | Export-CSV C:\out1.csv -Delimiter ";" -Encoding Unicode
```

Answer (score 0):

This script worked great for me but I couldn't get it to export directly to CSV so I used copy/paste from into Excel.

```
Get-MsolUser -all | Where-Object {$_.isLicensed -eq "True"} | Select UserPrincipalName,DisplayName,Licenses | Out-GridView
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as you dont know the powershell or scripting, you should automate the whole [powershell Export log](http://eventlogxp.com/blog/exporting-event-logs-with-windows-powershell/) process with standard windows instruments. There are many third party tools that can help. try searching for them . it will make ur work easier

Comment: This looks like extended promotion for FSPro Labs
http://betanews.com/2016/03/09/windows-10-advertising-in-ie-security-patch/
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36370603/1699210 http://stackoverflow.com/a/36323518/1699210 http://serverfault.com/a/767211/185961 http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/186828/41723 http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/184705/41723