# Office 365 Powershell - Export user to csv file

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

I took this script from that post : [Office 365 Powershell](https://serverfault.com/questions/517618/office-365-powershell-export-user-license-type-and-company-field-to-csv-file)
but when I run it, I receive that error :

> WARNING: More results are available. Please specify one of the All or
>   MaxResults parameters.

Where do I need to add the maxresults parameters in order to make the export possible?

```
$lines = @()
foreach($msolUser in (Get-MSOLUser -ALL | where {$_.isLicensed -eq $true}))
{
    $UserInfo = Get-User -identity $msolUser.UserPrincipalName
    foreach($license in $msolUser.Licenses)
    {
        $lines += New-Object PsObject -Property @{
                    "Nom/Prenom"="$($UserInfo.DisplayName)";
                    "Societe"="$($UserInfo.Company)";
                    "AdressePrincipale"="$($UserInfo.UserPrincipalName)";
                    "Licences"="$($license.AccountSKUid)"
                  }
    }
}
$lines | Export-CSV C:\out1.csv -Delimiter ";" -Encoding Unicode
```

Comment: Hi Yannick, how far did you get with this?

Comment: In order to work, you have to open session with azure AD and import session in exchange before running the script. The get-user command is only valid in exchange. out of that, the script work perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

By default commands like `Get-User` and `Get-MSOLUser` only give you the first 200 objects. you have `-ALL` next to the `Get-MSOLUser` command but not next to the `GET-USER` cmdlet. try using `Get-USER -ALL`

Hope This Works,

Mike